# How to use groupby for multiple columns in pandas for the below shown image?

Tags: pandas

This is input table in pandas:
[image]

this is an output table as shown below:
[image]
dtype: int64


 Dear Friends, 

I am new to pandas, how to get the result is shown in the second image  using pandas. 
I am getting output as shown below using this approach

"df.groupby(['Months', 'Status']).size()"

Months  Status

Apr-20  IW        2

        OW        1

Jun-20  IW        4

        OW        4

May-20  IW        3

        OW        2

dtype: int64

But how to convert this output as shown in the second image?
It will be more helpful if someone is able to help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Status', 'Months']).size().unstack()`

Comment: @ignoring_gravity - yop, comment was changed

Answer (score 2):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `margins=True` parameter, then if necessary remove last `Total` column, change order of columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with ordering of original column and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['Status'], df['Months'],  margins_name='Total', margins=True)
       .iloc[:, :-1]
       .reindex(df['Months'].unique(), axis=1)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  Status  Apr_20  May_20  Jun_20
0     IW       4       2       4
1     OW       1       2       4
2  Total       5       4       8
```

Comment: How to remove the below row is having  'Total', from your solutions, I got the Total at Top too, whereas I need to remove the below Total and also I would  like to add a column to the left side as shown in the second the image

Comment: @Balrajswamy - Add `df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, I could remove the Total at Bottom, Thanks a lot for your great help.

Comment: In addition to the above solutions, i want to add a column  at zero index.  when I tried to add a column using df.insert(0,'Column_name', 'XXX'),  but it went to second column. i did not know this.  pls suggest me that what is wrong in the syntax?

Comment: @Balrajswamy - First column in my solution `0,1,2` is called index, so if use `df.insert(0,'Column_name', 'XXX')` it add column before `Status`. If want set `index` to same values use `df.index = np.repeat('XXX', len(df))`

Comment: Dear Friend, I would like to add a list to the df at '0 ' index :

Comment: example:  <br>df['comp_name']=['XXX','KA','IN']
<br>df.index = np.repeat('XXX', df['comp_name'])

Comment: @Balrajswamy - then use `df.index = ['XXX','KA','IN']`

Answer (score 1):

Unstack, and then transpose:

```
df = df.groupby(['Months', 'Status']).size().unstack().T
```

To get a `total` row:

```
df.sum().rename('Total').to_frame().T.append(df)
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Status', 'Months']).size().unstack()` ?

Comment: Don't they want Status to be the index (btw, thanks for all your great answers!)?

Comment: hmmm, why answering for 1000 times answered dupes?

Comment: Sure sorry, will do so in the future

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great solutions , whereas how to add a row for Total shown in the second image?

Comment: ooops, not dupe, reopened